# Get the src of an image from HTML5 webcam

Tags: javascript, php, html, webcam

I have an application where the user will click on a picture from the webcam and save it to a database. I have added the plugin from [WebRTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos).

My code is as below:

```html
<form action="process.php" method="post">
  <div class="camera">
    <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
    <button id="startbutton">Take photo</button>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas">
  </canvas>
  <div class="output">
    <img id="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box.">
  </div>
  <script>
  var myImg = document.getElementById("photo").src;
  </script>
  <input type="submit" onclick="alert(myImg)">
  </form>
```

But when I click on submit, to check what it passes, it alerts empty! Why is it not showing the `src`?

**NB**: I am taking help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389392/capture-image-from-webcam-and-save-in-folder-using-php-and-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with `html` , `javascript` at Question

1. `img` `src` is still set to placeholder image when `input type="submit"` is clicked, refreshing `window` on `form` submission
2. `form` is being submitted before `img` element `src` is set to `data URI` at `photo.setAttribute('src', data);` within `takepicture`

Try setting `input type="submit"` `disabled` attribute to prevent `form` being submitted before `takepicture` is called; attaching `click` event to `#startbutton` ; within `#startbutton` `click` handler attaching `onload` event to `#photo` , which should `alert` `data URI` of `<img>` `src` after being set to `data URI` representation of `canvas` image set from `video` within `onload` handler; set `input type="submit"` `disabled` attribute to `false` to allow `form` to be submitted.

Note also that error may occur if `https:` protocol not used.

```
 getUserMedia() no longer works on insecure origins. 
 To use this feature, you should consider switching your 
 application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. 
 See [url] for more details.
```

---

```
<form>
  <div class="camera">
    <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
    <button id="startbutton">Take photo</button> 
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas">
  </canvas>
  <div class="output">
    <img id="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box."> 
  </div>
    <script>
     document.getElementById("startbutton").addEventListener("click", function() {
       document.getElementById("photo").onload = function() {
           console.log(this.src);
           alert(this.src);
           document.querySelector("input[type=submit]").disabled = false;
       };          
     })
  </script>
  <input type="submit" disabled>
</form>
```

plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/qzvEdtCnQnzXceIpDumA

Comment: @Nitish `form` does not appear to submit `src` of `img` ? Though this does not appear to be part of Question ?

Answer (score 1):

Define one default src first. Then replace that src with your taken photo:

```js
<script>
    var myImg = document.getElementById("photo").src;
</script>
```

```js
<div class="output">
    <img id="photo" src="" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box.">
  </div>
```

Comment: Now it alerts the source of my project, eg it alerts http://localhost/webcam. Not the actual data, which is shown when checked firebug

Comment: what you are passing in default src="" ?